# Find most significant bit without bitshifts

Tags: c++, performance, bitset

I am trying to find the [most significant bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering#Most_significant_byte) of unsigned number without using any bitshifts. This is what I have come up with, which looks very naive but it's very simple:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr uint8_t find_msb(const T& a_variable)
{
    static_assert(std::is_unsigned<T>::value, "Variable must be unsigned");

    constexpr uint8_t number_of_bits = std::numeric_limits<T>::digits;
    const std::bitset<number_of_bits> variable_bitset{a_variable};

    for (uint8_t msb = number_of_bits - 1; msb >= 0; msb--)
    {
        if (variable_bitset[msb] == 1)
            return msb + 1;
    }        
    return 0;
}
```

In C++17 this is a valid constexpr function and it appears it just vanishes into thin air with gcc, even with -O0: https://godbolt.org/z/pKI8fj.

But the non constexpr version is more involved: https://godbolt.org/z/eyj2bO.

In my use case I can use the constexpr version so it's not a big deal. How can I improve this code while maintaining readability and also without using any "smart" tricks and/or bitshifting?

Comment: Why don't you want to use bit-shifting?

Comment: If your goal is performance, have you done benchmarking to compare this function to bit shifting? Bit shifting is the usual way, and likely will be faster.

Comment: @200_success, I have done some benchmarking here: http://quick-bench.com/s8V2LQQ8rgyD6E0PnX_7B7DquM8. Don't know if I've done it right or not. But if the no bit-shift version is as fast as the bit-shift one,as it appears to be, I'd prefer to have some code that can be read and understood by an average Joe like me.
For some reason if you compile it with older versions of Clang the bitshift version(s) start to perform worse: http://quick-bench.com/o6IZaxnhAa_Zj2PGuIEDEWoqjaw

Comment: @esote, see above please.

Comment: For completeness, you can check [this CR link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/151312/integer-log2-implemented-using-binary-search) about other ways.

Comment: benchmarking with a `constexpr` argument isn't representative. Compilers are really good at optimizing code on constants. After hiding the argument inside a vector, here's what I get: http://quick-bench.com/0UodZdS2uBrTHXgw7slAQ7XIrj0

Comment: besides, average C++ programmers might know more about bit-shifting than `constexpr`; C++ is indeed often taught as a low-level, C-like language. Anyway, if someone cares about the most significant bit, he probably knows about bit-shifting too. If he isn't into bits at all, then maybe you should find another name for your function, like: `floor_log2`, or `previous_power_of_2`. But if you meet the rare guy who cares for the msb, knows more about constexpr and don't want to meddle with bits, then hide the implementation in a library with a reassuring set of easy-to-read tests on binary litterals

Comment: And please, change the `>= 0` to `!= 0` because if `a_variable` is zero, you go into an infinite loop

Comment: @papagagadid you mean `ceil_log2` instead, as better name?  ( `assert(find_msb(0x12u) == ceil(log2(0x12u)));`)

Comment: @Calak: well, I didn't *really* mean `ceil_log2`, just got confused, but obviously you're right!

Comment: @papagaga, wow. Your benchmark makes more sense now. Your arguments also make sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- use `std::uint8_t`, to avoid relying on something that [may or may not exist in the global namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13130023/673679).
- An unsigned type will always be `>= 0`. So if `a_variable` is 0, this will result in undefined behaviour by accessing something out of bounds of the bitset (and either crash or loop forever).
- If we're finding the "most significant bit", I don't think avoiding bitshifts makes it more readable. (This requires understanding of both `numeric_limits::digits`, and `std::bitset` instead).